# What was that space-time crack in WestWorld S4 at the dam?

Tags: westworld-2016

This seasons is supposedly taking place in physical reality, and despite popular belief, not in the mind of Dolores (Christina). One perfect cue to this fact is that Hale could extract or detach Dolores' pearl from the virtual model of the city at the tower, and that effectively shut down most of Dolores'. One counter argument to this would be the fact that she moseys around at the end in the "final test" in her Dolores clothes (where the heck would she have that there, although she may be delusional, and merely imagine those clothes on).

Maybe the pearl detachment also takes place in her mind, and imagines her inner reality accordingly.

In any ways, if the main scene of the events is not in a virtual reality in the mind of one or more of them, how is that "tear" what looked like the same gate to the "sublime" appear at the dam?

The depicted level of technology which is clearly in advance of our day, does still not consistent with whatever would be necessary to create whatever that thing was. #2 if on the other side, in fact, the digital world for the host is, what on earth is that gate supposed even represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current working theory is that (and I need to go back and review all the scenes where the Sublime crack is observed) can only be seen by hosts and not humans. I think it is more a spiritual (or virtual) thing where the sublime is calling hosts to "heaven".

From a more technical perspective, it could be signals that are produced by the hardware that governs the sublime, like a hologram, in the same way those glasses were used to project an image of Hale in the last episode.

So in short, it can only be seen by hosts, and if my theory is correct, it is only shown in scenes with hosts, so we see what the hosts see.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you saying that the tear is virtual and not real?  The question is working from the assumption that it is somehow real, so you should be explicit that you think the question is incorrect on that point.

Comment: Yep, see your point. Had a little go at adjusting the answer, and tried to make more explicit reference to it being a virtual projection.